# Global name error when importing a function

Tags: python, python-2.7

Trying to kill two birds with one stone I decided to write a bit of code that would let me practice python and calculus at the same time. I have two seperate files, Derivative.py and newton_method.py (I know I should get a bit better about naming my files correctly). The text from Derivatibe.py is as follows

```
def fx(value, function):
    x = value
    return eval(function)

def function_input(input):
    function = str(input)
    return function

def derivative_formula(x, h):
    return (fx(x - h, input_function) - fx(x + h, input_function)) / (2.0 * h)

def derivative_of_x(x):
    error = 0.0001
    h = 0.1
    V = derivative_formula(x, h)
    print V
    h = h / 2.0
    derivative_estimate = derivative_formula(x, h)
    while abs(derivative_estimate - V) < error:
        V = derivative_formula(x, h)
        h = h / 2.0
        derivative_estimate = derivative_formula(x, h)
        print derivative_estimate
    return derivative_estimate
```

And the text from newton_method.py is:

```
from Derivative import *

input_function = function_input(raw_input('enter a function with correct python syntax'))

E = 1 * (10 ** -10)

guessx = float(raw_input('Enter an estimate'))

def newton_method(guessx, E, function):
    x1 = guessx
    x2 = x1 - (fx(x1, input_function) / derivative_of_x(x1))
    while x2 - x1 < E:
        x1 = x2
        x2 = x1 - (fx(x1, input_function) / derivative_of_x(x1))
    return x2

print "The root of that function is %f" % newton_method(guessx, E, input_function)
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "newton_method.py", line 17, in <module>
    print "The root of that function is %f" % newton_method(guessx, E,         input_function)
  File "newton_method.py", line 11, in newton_method
    x2 = x1 - (fx(x1, input_function) / derivative_of_x(x1))
  File "C:\Users\159micarn\Desktop\Python\Derivative.py", line 15, in derivative_of_x
    V = derivative_formula(x, h)
  File "C:\Users\159micarn\Desktop\Python\Derivative.py", line 10, in derivative_formula
    return (fx(x - h, input_function) - fx(x + h, input_function)) / (2.0 * h)
NameError: global name 'input_function' is not defined
```

Do I need to declare input_function in Derivative.py? I would have thought that declaring it in newton_method.py would have been enough.

Answer (score 0):

Modules do not have access to the namespaces of the modules that import them. Imagine 10 modules importing `Derivative.py`. Which `input_function` would it use? `input_function` is just and another value and should be an additional input parameter to `derivative_formula`.